# Table doesn't exist trying to connect to RDS mysql Database

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-session

I am having trouble connecting to the RDS database I created from the Elastic beanstalk console. The app is deployed ok, but I get an internal server error from the webpage every time I try using the database in the app. For example, if I try to add a user.

Here is one of the logs

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'ebdb.note' doesn't exist")
```

```
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ("mysql+pymysql://"+ os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'] + ":" 
                                         + os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD']+ "@" 
                                         + os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'] 
                                           + ":3306/ebdb")
```

`config.py`

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  # Load environment variables from .env file

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY') 
       SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ("mysql+pymysql://"+ os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'] + ":" 
                                         + os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD']+ "@" 
                                         + os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'] 
                                           + ":3306/ebdb")
    SESSION_PERMANENT = False
```

I have the RDS database set to publicly accessible.

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk confusingly calls Environment Variables "environment properties". Here's the official documentation, which includes a step-by-step guide for setting them in the Elastic Beanstalk console: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html

Comment: @MarkB Thank you for the response. So is the issue with my DATABASE_URI in the code I provided, or with the configuration in my elastic beanstalk console?
Would I need to setup instance subnets, or make the IP address public in order for my databse to be connected?

Comment: You should already have VPC subnets, you can't run RDS or Elastic Beanstalk without them. RDS should **not** have a public IP address, since Elastic Beanstalk should be running in the same VPC that the RDS instance is in. You really need to get the server logs from Elastic Beanstalk to see what the actual issue connecting to the database is. It could be a timeout, or it could be a password error or something. The solution will be different depending on what the actual error is.

Comment: Also, I'm curious how you were actually setting environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk, such that the code like `os.environ['RDS_USERNAME']` would work, when you appeared to not know how to set environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: @MarkB I got the environment variables from this website
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html

Comment: Also correct me if I'm wrong but, in the Elastic Beanstalk "Create Environment" Form in the Network and Database section, if I don't select a VPC or subnet, my app will be using the default one provided by AWS?

Comment: Those environment variables will only work if you had Elastic Beanstalk create the RDS instance. Did you do that? And yes, if you don't select a VPC, it uses the default VPC.

Comment: Yes, I did have Elastic Beanstalk create the RDS instance. I used its create application form.
And I suppose the brackets around the DATABASE_URI string in my code won't effect anything?